# Unity VR -make GIU text face main camera

Tags: user-interface, text, virtual-reality

there is a cube as a trigger in the VR scene. When looked at - GUI text appears.  I wish that text to face the main camera independently from the angle at which trigger cube was activated.  So far I have tried to make the the Canvas as a child of the main camera, but that disables gaze input (I see reticle, but it does not become a circle while looking at the cube).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of making that UI face the user, but either [Billboard](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CameraFacingBillboard) or [Transform.LookAt()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) should get you there...

Keep the Canvas in World Space, tho. Unity also provides a good [VR Sample Package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/51519) for free. Finally here's [my answer to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766211/hover-menu-on-skybox-in-unity/44769674#44769674) with some more details.