# Hover Menu on Skybox in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I have a question about a VR/AR-interaction I would like to create.

I want to have an image that acts as a skybox to give an aerial perspective on a landscape and allow users to hover over a part of the image to show a small panel with a description of the object they are looking at.

For example, if I have a skybox of a cityscape and wanted to allow users to hover over a building and have a popup interaction displaying the name of the building, what would be the best strategy to do this?

I have the skybox created but have run into perspective issues when trying to add a button over a specific object.

Is this possible with this approach or would I need a textured landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually use [billboards](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CameraFacingBillboard) (images that always face the camera) to create hotspots on top of either cubic or spherical skyboxes. This is illustrated here in our [cardboard demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=digital.neutral.apex.travelapp)

Often to place items like info text or popups, I just:

- parent the content to an empty GameObject
- offset the content to the desired distance (along the z axis)
- rotate the parent to position the content where it needs to appear

On GearVR, since the user/camera is always in the center the above is like having a billboard.

The hotspots/buttons have a collider attached and you can shoot a ray, on Late Update, with the camera position & rotation to determine if the user is hovering (looking at) a given hotpot. Two helpful classes to get you started are Camera [ScreenPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) and [Physics.RayCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

To do precise cutouts of content in a skybox (like highlighting a specific building) we usually use a cubemap based skybox and do the masking/post-processing in Photoshop. Then we layer the images top of the corresponding background skybox panel in unity and turn them on/off as needed. To simplify lining things up in Unity, I usually use a "custom skybox" which is basically 6 quads facing in.

hth.